# Как использовать WebDriverWait вместе с find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium

Нашел вод такой пример

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Подскажите как вместо поиска по id искать по заданному шаблону

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='WPLANG']/option[@selected='selected']")
```

как то так что ли

```
try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='WPLANG']/option[@selected='selected']")
        )
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Неизвестно, что ты имеешь ввиду под описанием элемента,и как мы должны понять что ты имеешь ввиду,и у тебя немного не понятный и усложненный код,но вообще,чтобы найти элементы с помощью xpath, нужно  в исследовании элемента скопировать путь нужного файла с помощью xpath , и вписать его значение,например:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox() #ну или в твоем случае допустим хром
*нахождение, и копирование нужно элемента с помощью xpath*
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]').click()  # ну или нужное тебе действие 
browser.implicitly_wait(3) #твое время в секундах 
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]').click() # ну или нужное тебе действие
```

А вообще команда browser.implicitly_wait используется только для открытия и прогрузки страницы,проще использовать в уже после полного запуска команду time.sleep
(если хочешь выяснить твою проблему,и я не смог помочь, то попробуй почитать это руководство: https://habr.com/ru/post/250975/)